# Visual Studio Code: running preLaunchTask with multiple tasks

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I am trying to figure out how to run multiple tasks at once in the prelaunchtask of the launch.json file.

My code in the tasks.json is as follows:

```
    "version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "CleanUp_Client",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "rm",
        "args": [
            "-f",
            "Client"
        ],
    },
    {
        "label": "Client_Build",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "g++",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "client.cpp",
            "-o",
            "Client",
            "-lssl",
            "-lcrypto"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "problemMatcher": "$gcc"
    }
]
```

In the launch.json for the preLaunchTask parameter if I only put the build task it works, however I want to run multiple tasks, in this case is the CleanUp_Client and Client_Build.

I tried adding another preLaunchTask - However it looks like you can only use that parameter once, so then I tried:

`"preLaunchTask": "build" + "clean",`
`"preLaunchTask": "build"; "clean",`
`"preLaunchTask": "build" & "clean",`
`"preLaunchTask": "build" && "clean",`

All with no success, not the correct syntax.

Also as a second part to this I would like to know how the group part of this works, and what it means for "isDefault": true.

For your reference: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Here is something that will work. Basically you make another task in which you include all the other tasks that you want to run on your preLaunchTask with the `dependsOn`  keyword.

Code for reference:

```
    "tasks": [
    {
        "label": "CleanUp_Client",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "rm",
        "args": [
            "-f",
            "Client"
        ]
    },
    {
        "label": "Client_Build",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "g++",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "client.cpp",
            "-o",
            "Client",
            "-lssl",
            "-lcrypto"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "problemMatcher": "$gcc"
    },
    {
        "label": "Build",
        "dependsOn": [
            "CleanUp_Client",
            "Client_Build"
        ]
    }
]
```

In this case you would set your preLaunchTask to "Build" and it will run both tasks.

I am curious if anybody else knows an alternative or the correct syntax to just run several tasks from the launch.json preLaunchTask

Comment: Is this still working for you?
I configured my setup this way but the vscode debugger just hangs.

Comment: In Code 1.39.2, I am able to link together multiple tasks provided they are not of the `build` type. All `build` tasks fail if they are included in a list. This looks like a Visual Studio Code bug.

Answer (score 7):

I agree with @Revx0r answer, but there is important notice: you need to add to  last task `dependsOrder` field, if you want to **run it in sequence**:

```
{
    "label": "Build",
    "dependsOrder": "sequence",
    "dependsOn": [
        "CleanUp_Client",
        "Client_Build"
    ]
}
```