# Is there any way to step through a VScode - generated .JSON file?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to follow this VScode tutorial (https://hackernoon.com/how-to-set-up-c-debugging-in-vscode-using-a-makefile), and I've gotten to the point of creating the 'launch.json' file. In looking at the file I see there are a number of variables like '${workspaceFolder}' and '${fileDirname}', which I suspect evaluate to VScode workspace values.

Is there any way in VScode to step through this .JSON file and see what the variables evaluate to, or alternatively print them to the console when the .JSON file runs?

TIA,

Frank

Comment: there is no such thing as "stepping through JSON". you can step through a JSON parser, or a code that handles the parsed JSON. see also https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Code [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_how-can-i-know-a-variables-actual-value) states:

> One easy way to check a variable's runtime value is to create a VS Code [task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) to output the variable value to the console. For example, to see the resolved value for `${workspaceFolder}`, you can create and run (**Terminal** > **Run Task**) the following simple 'echo' task in `tasks.json`:

An example of a basic echo task for a bash configuration of some of these variables would look like:

Tasks.json:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "TestEcho",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "echo '${workspaceFolder}' File: '${file}'"
        }
    ]
}
```

In your launch.json, you can set this up to run as a `preLaunchTask`, so that before any debugging occurs, it will perform this task first:

Example launch.json:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "bashdb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Bash-Debug Test (simplest configuration)",
            "program": "${file}",
            "preLaunchTask": "TestEcho"
        }
    ]
}
```

Note how the `preLaunchTask` is set to `TestEcho` which matches the `label` in the tasks.json.

Example output after starting a debug configuration:

[image: example output]

A list of these variables can be found [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_predefined-variables).

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I was unable to get the task/launch.json files to behave as you described. When I copy/pasted the launch.json file to my VScode workspace, I got a 'problem' showing that  The 'bashdb' type entry was not recognized, and the flyover suggested I use 'node' instead.   I'm running VScode on a Debian Linux system if that makes a difference.

Comment: @user3765883 my code was mainly an example, you will probably have to tweak it some to get it to work. Your linked tutorial you are following has a launch.json file and task example. Perhaps look at those too. Looking at the tutorial, it actually already uses a `preLaunchTask`, so you may need to specify multiple tasks, which is doable as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51599106/visual-studio-code-running-prelaunchtask-with-multiple-tasks.  I think it will be a matter of using the task.json in my post with multiple `preLaunchTasks` in the launch.json in the tutorial.

Comment: I.e. you shouldn't need to worry about the bashdb part - use the launch.json as seen in the tutorial but modify it some to use the tasks.

Comment: thanks - I will do my best and report back ;)

Comment: please avoid answering duplicates